# Can't compile servlet using command line

Tags: servlets, compilation

I'm trying to compile a servlet which sets session data for my site. However I'm having big problems trying to import other class files which the servlet relies on.

I need to import my custom made `MySQL` class file which is located in `evo.net. (WEB-INF/classes/evo/net)`. This is already compiled and works perfectly.

And I also need to import my custom made Encryption class for encrypting passwords using it's `md5()` method. This is located in `evo.common (WEB-INF/classes/evo/common)`. This is already compiled and works perfectly too.

My Session servlet is located in the same package as my `MySQL` class `(evo.net or WEB-INF/classes/evo/net)`.

I'm setting the classpaths as follows:

> set classpath=;D:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
>   7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;D:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\evo\common\Encryption;D:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
>   7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\evo\net\MySQL

Is this the wrong way to set multiple classpaths? As its throwing 'cannot find symbol' errors. If I just set the classpath pointing at the `servlet-api.jar` it fixes the `javax` cannot find symbol errors, but when I add the others on the `classpath` it doesnt work. Help much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The classpath must contain jar files, and the directories that are the roots of package trees: `D:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes`. But you really, really should compile all your classes at once, and use a standard build tool like gradle to do that.

Comment: Could you explain to me step by step on how to do this? I don't want to use any third party applications like eclipse. Thanks

Comment: How to do what? Use gradle? There's documentation for that.

Comment: ok ive just made Encryption.jar and MySQL.jar. Just tried to set them on the classpath but im still getting the same error, however servlet-api.jar doesnt throw any errors

Comment: Have you read my comment? You don't need to make jars. Just put the right directory in the classpath: `D:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes`.

Comment: I did put the right classpaths in, as follows:

set classpath=;D:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;D:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\evo\common\Encryption;D:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\evo\net\MySQL

Seperated with a semicolor ";"

Comment: Again, read my comment. I did specifically mention that the **root** of the package tree must be in the classpath. I did specifically say that what you need to add is the directory `D:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes`. I did that twice. Now three times. Did you do that? No. Instead, you added `D:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\evo\common\Encryption` and `D:\Ap‌​ache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\evo\net\MySQL`. Why? Why don't you just read what I write?

Comment: Sorry im a little tired. I done what you asked and it's now worked!! thanks so much buddy :)